# When calling gapi.auth.signIn() with Contacts scope and offline access, the user has to accept the auth dialog twice

Tags: google-plus, google-contacts-api

After a user has already accepted the auth dialog, he should not have to accept it again. However, when including the contacts scope (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/) and asking for offline access, the user has to accept a 2nd auth dialog in order to sign in.  The first auth dialog does not ask the user for offline access, whereas the 2nd dialog does.  Here are the repro steps:

Put a sign-in button on the page that triggers the following javascript call to gapi.auth.signIn():

```
var myParams = {
    'clientid' : 'myClientId',
    'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
    'callback' : 'handleAuthResult',
    'scope' : 'https://mail.google.com/ https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'accesstype' : 'offline'
};
gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
function handleAuthResult(authRe) {
    console.log(authRe);
}
```

1. Click the sign-in button once, you will see an auth dialog with all of the permissions except for offline access.  Click "Accept" and handleAuthResult receives a valid access token.
2. Click the sign-in button a 2nd time, and you will be prompted to grant offline access.  Click "Accept", and handleAuthResult receives a valid access token.  However, the user should not have to click "Accept" a 2nd time.
3. Click the sign-in button a 3rd time, and you will NOT be prompted to accept anymore permissions. The auth dialog quickly opens and closes, and handleAuthResult receives a valid access token.

I do not want to make returning users have to accept a 2nd auth dialog.  Ideally, the offline access permission should appear in the 1st dialog.

I have also noticed that this only happens when I include the contacts scope (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/).  Removing that scope does not trigger the 2nd auth dialog that asks only for offline access.

Any help on how to get around this?  Is this a bug on Google's end?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it this is expected behaviour. If you request offline access, the user will always be prompted to authorize offline access when they authenticate. Offline access and automatic subsequent logins are not compatible together.

Comment: If I use the server side flow, then the use does not have to re-authenticate.  Also, after re-authenticating the 2nd time, the user does not have to re-authenticate a 3rd time.  All subsequent logins after the 2nd login are automatic.